# Why shouldn't I switch between "COMPUTE STATS" and "COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS" in Impala?

Tags: hive, cloudera, impala

According to Cloudera documentation, I am not supposed to switch between these types of computing statistics through lifetime of a table. Can someone explain why? I believe stats are computed just fine after switch.

Link to documentation where I found this recommendation: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-16-x/topics/impala_perf_stats.html#perf_stats_examples

Answer (score 1):

They behave as two different modes - if you switch from one to the other, it will discard all state from the other. E.g. if you run COMPUTE STATS after COMPUTE INCREMENTAL STATS, all the incremental stats will be discarded.

So nothing that bad happens, it's just that it doesn't do anything clever.